# QPainter paints under the widget's background color (background defined in styleSheet)

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpainter, paintevent, qstyle

I want to draw a line on top of the widget, but visually **QPainter** draws it under the widget if the widget has background color.

Paint event function in which I'm trying to draw the line:

```
void PaintHelper::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);

    // Set up the "line"
    QRect rect = ui->frame->frameRect();
    rect.setY(ui->frame->parentWidget()->size().rheight() / 2);
    rect.setHeight(5);
    rect.setWidth(rect.width() * 1.5);

    // Draw the line
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(234, 33, 123), 20));
    painter.drawRect(rect);
}
```

The button (see the screenshot below) is needed to call *repaint* (this didn't help anyway)

```
void PaintHelper::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    repaint();
}
```

And the simplest .qss file for that QFrame on which I want to draw the line:

```
QFrame{
    background-color: #B0A686;
}
```

[Thats how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uAPZ.jpg)

Comment: Seems you are painting to the parent widget (`PaintHelper`) and then the child frame (`ui->frame`) is painted over it. This is natural way how Qt works, parent widget is painted and then its children are painted over it. You will need to override the `paintEvent` method of the frame instead of the `paintEvent` method of the parent widget. But it will not be easy, you will have to define your custom class derived from `QFrame` and then use this derived class in UI form. Or you should be also able to do it using event filter but it will be somewhat more hackish...

Comment: Yeah, seems I have to create a child class. Thanks